# Message: listener timeout after waiting for [30000] ms

Tags: java

I am trying to implement simple CRUD operation on Elasticsearch using groovy and grails
some time I am able to create an index and some time I am getting below-mentioned exception that is time out, I have tried some many ways none of them is working. I stuck here can some help me to get out from this.
***below the exception I have attached the code which I am using here, please go through it and check whether it is correct or not**

***Exception***

> Error |2018-05-29 23:13:18,320 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR
>   errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - IOException occurred when processing
>   request: [GET] /Sharama1/person/addPerson
>           listener timeout after waiting fo
>           List item
>          r [30000] ms. Stacktrace follows:
>           Message: listener timeout after waiting for [30000] ms
>               Line | Method
>           ->>  661 | get                                   in org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$SyncResponseListener
>           - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
>           |    220 | performRequest                        in org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient
>           |    192 | performRequest . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
>           |    428 | performRequest                        in org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient
>           |    414 | performRequestAndParseEntity . . . .  in     ''
>           |    299 | index                                 in     ''
>           |     -2 | invoke0 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl
>           |     62 | invoke                                in     ''
>           |     43 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl
>           |    497 | invoke                                in java.lang.reflect.Method
>           |   1426 | jlrMethodInvoke . . . . . . . . . . . in org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor
>           |    189 | invoke                                in org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSite

***create index code ***

```
def addPerson={
    RestHighLevelClient client=ESService.getClient()
    Map<String,Object> jsonMap = new HashMap<>();
    jsonMap.put("firstName","abcd");
    jsonMap.put("lastName","xyz");
    jsonMap.put("date",new Date());
    jsonMap.put("message","Hugh data Index mapping");
    IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest("person1","hughdata","4").source(jsonMap);
    IndexResponse res =  client.index(indexRequest);
    String index = res.getIndex()
    String type = res.getType()
    String id = res.id
    long version = res.getVersion()
    DocWriteResponse.Result result = res.getResult();

    if (result == DocWriteResponse.Result.CREATED){
        println("index created = "+result)
    }
    else if (result == DocWriteResponse.Result.UPDATED){
        println("index Updated = "+result)
    }
    ["index":index,"type": type,"id":id,"version":version]
}
```

***Create a client code***

```
    class ESService {
    RestHighLevelClient client=null
    //TransportClient client=null
        def RestHighLevelClient getClient(){
            try {
                String hostname = "localhost"
                int port = 9200
                String scheme = "http"

                client = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost",9200,"http")))

                boolean pingResponse = client.ping()

                if (pingResponse == true) {
                    print("connection established..." + pingResponse);
                } else {
                    print("connection not established. Try again : " + pingResponse)
                }
                /*return client*/
            }
            catch (ElasticsearchException e){
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            return client
        }
}
```

***Buildconfig.groovy***

```
 dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
    // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.27'
    // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1100-jdbc41'
    test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0-grails-2.3"
    compile group: 'org.elasticsearch', name: 'elasticsearch', version: '6.0.1'
    compile group: 'org.elasticsearch.client', name: 'elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client', version: '6.0.1'
    compile('com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticsearch:1.11.123')
    compile('com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticloadbalancingv2:1.11.123')
}
```

Comment: `[GET] /Sharama1/person/addPerson`. Where does this call come from?

Comment: Off topic: Please get used to finish every line of command with a semicolon `;`. Your code is a real mess.

Comment: [GET] /Sharama1/  is my default url ,  added persosn/addPerson to default url, to make a addPerson action called

Comment: in Groovy it is not necessary to have semicolon at the end of the line ( ; is optional in groovy)